# How to follow open-close principle when changing interface

Tags: design-patterns

There maybe sometime I need to change the interface for some new demand. Maybe I need to change the signature of the method or add some new method to the interface. This seem like broke the open-close principle but the new method is indeed should be add to the already existed interface.

Can someone give me some suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the decorator can help you? https://www.baeldung.com/java-decorator-pattern let me know that I can implement an exhaustive answer

Answer (score 0):

You might consider defining a different interface and adding it to the existing implementation. That is a good approach if you have to add a new method that does different things from what already implemented.

If you instead have to alter an existing method by adding more parameters, I suppose you don't have many choices. But to be fair, this is not really a big issue, unless you're writing a library...

In C# you can write Extension Methods, which allow you to define methods running on an interface (or class) without modifying the existing code. This could be an option in case the new method's implementation is ultimately calling the existing one.